# Linq to Sql Add method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, mapping

Lets Assume we have this table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Students
(
  StudentID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.StudentLoans
(
  LoanID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  StudentID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Students(StudentID),
  Amount int
);
```

and we have the following code in the form code

```
using(var myContextInstance=new YourContext())
{
    var student = new Student(){Name = "user962206"};
    var studentLoan = new StudentLoan(){Amount = 50000};
    student.StudentLoans.Add(studentLoan);
    myContextInstance.Students.InsertOnSubmit(student);
    myContextInstance.SubmitChanges();
}
```

and lets further assume that I drag and dropped my table into my O/R Designer and at the same time I have a class of `LINQ to SQL classes`

What does each line of code here do? specifically the

```
student.StudentLoans.Add(studentLoan);
```

what does the .Add(studentLoan) method specifically do?

Comment: Is this linq to sql or linq to entities?  They are different things.

Comment: SubmitChanges is specific to linq-to-sql only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will insert a new entry in StudentLoans table. The StudentId of this new entry will have the value of the newly added student.

***edit***

The other way

```
using(var myContextInstance=new YourContext())
{
    // create a new student instance
    var student = new Student(){Name = "user962206"};
    // inserts this student by calling SubmitChanges; student.StudentID will have new value from database
    myContextInstance.Students.InsertOnSubmit(student);
    myContextInstance.SubmitChanges();

   // create a new student load object
    var studentLoan = new StudentLoan(){Amount = 50000};
   // assign the StudentID
    studentLoan.StudentID = student.StudentID; 
    // you can assign the student via the Student property also
    // or studentLoan.Student = student;

    // save the new StudentLoan object into the database
    myContextInstance.StudentLoans.InsertOnSubmit(studentLoan);
    myContextInstance.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: but why does it have the student.StudentLoans.Add(studentLoan)? can it be used as StudentLoans.Add(studentLoan) instead? if you mean StudentID the StudentID in the Student Table or the StudentId on the StudentLoans table?

Comment: you can use StudentLoans.Add(studentLoan), but you have to know the StudentID value

Comment: The StudentID in the Student Table

Comment: what if I want to do it the other way around? how would I do that?

Comment: lftode can you rephrase your answer its very confusing.

Comment: lftode where can I see the full specifications of that method or library ?

Comment: lftode is in the MSDN site? I can't seem to find it.